# why cookies are always null after postback

Tags: c#, asp.net

i am trying to maintain some data into cookies but after postback if i check the value of the cookies in pageload the value is always null

this is how i set and get the cookies

```
private static string GetCookie(string name)
{
    return HttpContext.Current.Response != null ? HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies[name].Value : string.Empty;
}

private static void SetCookie(string name, string value)
{
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies[name].Value = value;
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies[name].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(ExpireTimeInDays);
}
```

Comment: From where are you calling these methods? From a particular event in an ASPX page? Can you show the code in your page or handler that calls these?

Comment: I think you need to get the cookie from the request.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

GetCookie() needs to use Request.Cookie not Response.Cookie

Answer (score 3):

[HttpResponse.Cookies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.cookies.aspx)

> ASP.NET includes two intrinsic cookie
> collections. The collection accessed
> through the Cookies collection of
> HttpRequest contains cookies
> transmitted by the client to the
> server in the Cookie header. The
> collection accessed through the
> Cookies collection of HttpResponse
> contains new cookies created on the
> server and transmitted to the client
> in the Set-Cookie header.
>
> After you add a cookie by using the
> HttpResponse..::.Cookies collection,
> the cookie is immediately available in
> the HttpRequest..::.Cookies
> collection, even if the response has
> not been sent to the client.

So change your get to use the Request